# Adding Animation to panels when they are made visible in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am creating an application in WPF and the window has one main grid with 3 rows. There are 3 buttons in the 3rd row and on the click of each button, a panel is displayed in the 2nd grid row. I achieved this by setting the visibility option of the panels. However, now I would like to add an effect/animation as the panels become visible. I don't know where to start, so kindly help.

My xaml code is similar to this

```
<Window>
   <Grid>
      <!-- 3row definitions -->
      <Grid Grid.Row="0"> </Grid>
      <Grid Name="panel1" Grid.row="1" Visibility="Hidden"></Grid>
      <Grid Name="panel2" Grid.row="1" Visibility="Hidden"></Grid>
      <Grid Name="panel3" Grid.row="1" Visibility="Hidden"></Grid>
      <Grid Grid.Row="2"></Grid>
   </Grid>
 </Windows>
```

Xaml.cs code to change the visibility is similar to this

```
 private void Image_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        panel2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        panel3.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  A simple search for animation in WPF will give you a lot of tutorials and resources - is there something specific you need assistance with?

Comment: I need the panels sliding in as they are made visible on the button clicks. I don't know where to start. As I searched, I found the codes to be very complicated. Some made use of EntranceThemeTransition but I couldn't get to use that in my application.

Answer (score -1):

this can be done using expression studio, in expression blend open your wpf projects, there you can add animations to your wpf controls, you also need to start and stop animation when your application launches,

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpGvl1TayAQ

here is a video tutorial, you can get more tutorials by googling it,